# How to calculate my a priori sample size when using a probit regression?

Tags: stata, sample-size

I want to calculate my a priori sample size for a probit regression analysis expecting a small effect size. I attempted to do so using GPower. However, the program does not allow for a probit regression sample size calculation. I am working my main analyses on Stata. Is there anyway I can use G*Power to calculate a sample size for this type of regression? I also searched in the current literature for similar studies and view the sample sizes. However, my topic exploring the effects of financial stability variables on well being within a Syrian context is not common in the literature. Are there other ways to calculate my required sample size?